# mongoimport is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I have installed the recent version of MongoDb version 4.4 but I cannot find the mongoimport.exe file there I have setup the custom path properly so that's not the issue so what seems to be the problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out that the latest release you have to install the [database Tools](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools) separately in my case I was using Windows 10 so I downloaded a zip file containing the files and extracted them to the bin folder that is

> C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin

ps the mongodb Team also changed the syntax they are now using the forward slash  `/`